# Internal Energy Change of Adiabatic/Isolated System at Constant Volume?

Tags: thermodynamics

If we take an isolated system at constant volume in which chemical reaction happens than it is said that heat of reaction changes internal energy of the system. As far as I know internal energy takes into account all microscopic energy of the system such as kinetic energy of atomic and molecular motion and potential energy of interaction of all bonds in the system (intermolecular and chemical). If we have an reaction which releases heat (exothermic) than potential energy of chemical bonds goes down and microscopic kinetic energy goes up (temperature increases). Change in micro kinetic energy is the same as change in potential energy due to energy conservation. Since internal energy takes into account both types of these energies, its sum must remain the same due to energy conservation. If so, than internal energy doesn't change. What is a problem here?

Comment: Who say / where it is said that if we take a rigid isolated system in which a chemical reaction happens then the heat of reaction changes the internal energy of the system? Your entire discussion is correct, it is basically the first principle. It is just the premise, which I don't know from where is coming from, that is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

When they say that the heat of reaction changes the internal energy, what they mean is that the internal energy (or the enthalpy) changes **at constant temperature (i.e., if the initial and final temperatures are held the same)**.  If the change in internal energy is forced to be zero in an adiabatic enclosure, then the temperature must change to offset the heat of reaction.  For an exothermic reaction, this means that, for the internal energy to remain constant, the temperature must rise to offset the negative heat of reaction.

Comment: Hi Chet. As you know, I am not a chemist like you. But can I think of the heat of combustion as the potential for heating due to temperature increase (the potential for energy transfer by heat) even if that potential cannot be realized in the case of  combustion in an adiabatic enclosure? The phrase "heat of reaction" always bugs me since the reaction need not result in heating. Some others (chemistry minded) on this site keep insisting that "heat content" means containing heat. And that  heat can be considered a property of the system as in, for example, the case of an isochoric process.

Comment: @BobD in adiabatic enclosure that heating certainly causes the T to rise. Why it can't be “realised“?

Comment: @Alchimista. how you are defining "heating"?

Comment: @BobD Actually, I'm a chemical engineer.  I would not think of the heat of combustion in that way.  I would think of the heat of combustion as the amount of heat that has to be removed to hold the system at constant temperature (and pressure).  I'm not bugged by the phrase heat of reaction if I regard it as the change in enthalpy between the products and the reactants, which is equal to the amount of heat that must be added to the reaction mixture in a constant pressure process to hold the mixture at constant temperature.

Comment: So the first part of this refers to the change in a state property (enthalpy) between well-specified end states of a system, and the second part refers to how it is would be measured.

Comment: @ChetMiller Sorry about that (chemical engineer, not chemist). I have no issue with your points about heat of combustion in terms of enthalpy. The issue I have (with others) is that when the change in enthalpy is due strictly to heat transfer, they say that means "heat" is a property since it equals enthalpy, which is a property. They make a similar argument about work. They say work is a property if it is adiabatic work, since work equal change in internal energy which is a property. THAT's what bugs me. I'd like your view on that.

Comment: @BobD What can I say?  I agree with you.

Comment: @BobD and OP: the heating is right as formulated in the OP question. Potential energy stored in bonds gets converted in kinetic energy. The system T rises. The internal energy is constant. See also Miller comment.

Comment: @ChetMiller Can you clarify something for me. When you said "changes at constant temperature (i.e., if the initial and final temperatures are held the same)" did you really mean the temperature of the system is constant during the heat of reaction, or just that the initial an final temperatures are the same?

Comment: @BobD Well, since enthalpy is a state function, the only thing that matters is the initial and final temperatures.

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes, that's why I asked for clarification on "constant temperature" because all that matters is initial and final h is the same and I couldn’t see any way that combustion could be held at constant temperature.

Comment: BTW, did you look at my answer? It goes to my statement to you “But can I think of the heat of combustion as the potential for heating due to temperature increase”.  The combustion is the same in Fig 1 and Fig 2, but in Fig 2 there is no “heating” (the temperature of the bomb increases and there is no heat transfer) whereas in Fig 1 there is.  But in Fig 2 there is still the potential for heating.  This is what I meant by “the potential for heating”.

Comment: @BobD I'm really confused about your discussion of Figs. 1 and 2.  Fig. 1 determines the change in internal energy of combustion because the heat transferred from the reaction mixture to the water and calorimeter occurs at essentially constant temperature for the reaction mixture (except for a slight increase).  In Fig. 2, the heat transferred from the reaction mixture to the container is much less, so the temperature of the reaction mixture increases substantially.  So, in this case, it is much more difficult and inaccurate to estimate the internal energy change of combustion.

Comment: @ChetMiller Let’s start by focusing on Fig 1. First, do we both agree there is no change in the internal energy of the reaction mixture plus water since the combination is an isolated system (inside a rigid adiabatic outer container)?

Comment: @BobD. Yes.  We do agree, if we also include the calorimeter along with the water.

Comment: @ChetMiller OK, then when you said "Fig 1 determines the change in internal energy of combustion" are you then referring to the negative change in internal energy of the bomb or the equal positive change in internal energy of the water (assumes we can neglect the heat capacities of everything else) for a total change of zero?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123648/discussion-between-chet-miller-and-bob-d).

Answer (score 0):

Heat is also a form of Energy. It is defined as the energy that flows into or out of a system because of difference in temperature between the thermodynamic system and its surrounding. It occurs at the boundary of the system.

Now, as you have taken the system to be Adiabatic or isolated there is no heat released into the surrounding, it's still contained in the system as the heat is the exchange of energy between the system and the surrounding but that's not possible.

So, basically Q=0 and the energy that is released in breaking of bonds completely converts to Kinetic Energy making change in internal energy=0.

Comment: This what I said in my question. After talking about this question with others, answer to this question seems to be in how we define internal energy or what is our reference state. In thermodynamics, energy stored in chemical bonds is usually not taken into account as internal energy because we usually define reference state as ideal gas. In ideal gas there are no intermolecular interactions. Such reference state is good because we can track/calculate temperature changes in system via changes in internal energy.

Comment: So, we can pretend like heat of reaction is like heat exchanged with surroundings regardless of system being isolated since it has the same effect. If we pick reference state like I did than we can't calculate temperature changes via internal energy changes since according to my definiton internal energy doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

> Since internal energy takes into account both types of these energies,
> its sum must remain the same due to energy conservation. If so, than
> internal energy doesn't change. What is a problem here?

That is correct and there is no problem. Heating is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference. Whether or not heat is actually released in a reaction depends on how you define the system and where exactly heat transfer, if any, occurs.

FIG 1 below is a sketch of an Oxygen Bomb Calorimeter. It is a device that measures the heat of chemical reactions or physical changes.

The combustion process takes place in the steel bomb. The steel bomb is immersed in water. Both are placed in a rigid insulated outer container. We define the contents of the outer container as our system. Since the outer container is both insulated and rigid, our system is isolated, i.e., it can not exchange heat or work with the environment outside the outer container.

Combustion takes place. The internal chemical potential energy of the fuel is converted to internal kinetic energy and the temperature of the contents of the steel bomb suddenly increases. The temperature of the steel bomb is now greater than the water it is immersed in so there is heat transfer from the bomb to the water. All of the heat transfer occurs within the isolated system. Heat lost by the bomb equals heat gained by the water and internal energy is unchanged.

Now consider FIG 2. It is the same steel bomb but not immersed in water and now with thermal insulation around the bomb. Again we have an isolated system. Combustion takes place as before converting potential to kinetic energy and raising the temperature of the bomb. There is no change in internal energy of the bomb. However there is no heat transfer involved as occurred in FIG 1. *The fact that there is no heat transfer involved does not change the heating potential or heating value of the combustion process.* In fact, that potential is determined by the Oxygen Bomb Calorimeter of FIG 1.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, I actually figured it out later. It all depends on how we define internal energy or what do we include within it. In thermodynamics, energy stored in chemical bonds is not usually taken into account as internal energy. We usually take ideal gas as a reference in which there are no intermolecular interactions. So, in example of exothermic reaction we can pretend that heat of reaction is like heat which came from surroundings regardless of system being isolated since in both scenarios it has the same effect.

Comment: Picking reference state as ideal gas is actually much better than how I defined it because we can calculate temperature change via change of internal energy which can't be done if you pick my reference state since internal energy doesn't change according to my reference. In order to calculate it, we would need to know energy of all chemical bonds in our reaction and calculate changes in average kinetic energy of atoms and molecules which is much more difficult and less practical especially for engineers like myself.

Comment: @DarioMirić There are a number of statements here that I take issue with, but by response would be too long to be appropriate in comments. Would you be interested in discussing this in Chat?

Comment: @DarioMirić take O2. Even treating it as ideal, the fact that there'are not intermolecular interactions (which by the way must be corrected depending on conditions, as usual) isn't relevant concerning the potential energy stored within the molecule. We do not pretend energy comes from the surrounding. This is indeed molecular (within the molecule).

Comment: @Bob D, no problem although I don't know how to start one.

Comment: Potential energy stored in chemical bonds is different from intermolecular bonds, I agree, but that doesn't change what I wanted to say. What I meant is that heat of reaction has the same effect on internal energy of the constant volume system like the heat which comes from surroundings. In both cases they tend to change the temperature of the system. If we don't include interatomic potential energy in internal energy (if that is what we pick as reference state) than we can calculate change in temperature by connecting it with changes in internal

Comment: If you take my definition of reference state which includes interatomic potential energy (internal energy includes energy stored in chemical bonds) than you can't connect temperature change in our isolated system with changes in internal energy because INTERNAL ENERGY DOESN'T CHANGE ACCORDING TO MY REFERENCE DUE TO ENERGY CONSERVATION. This is the reason why picking my reference isn't very practical.

Comment: I said we usually pick ideal gas as reference state, but yes as you said that isn't actually our reference in this example. That is my mistake. In thermodynamics, reference state (internal energy definition) doesn't usually include energy stored in chemical bonds, so in isolated system you can say that change in internal energy is due to heat of reaction, but you can't say that if you include energy stored in bonds in internal energy definition.

Comment: @DarioMirić Internal energy is the sum of ALL the potential and kinetic energies at the molecular and atomic levels. For potential energy this includes chemical, electrical, and even nuclear energy. In my view you can't exclude any of these when defining internal energy. On the other hand, if we are only interested in changes in internal energy, which is generally the case, we need only consider those forms that can potentially change. For example, we normally exclude nuclear.

Comment: So, unless you are defining an isolated system different than I (which is one that can't exchange heat, work, or mass with the surroundings) the internal energy of an isolated system cannot change. Period. That means the first statement in your post where “it is said”, whoever said it, is simply wrong.

Comment: The first hint of a problem with it is the statement “If we take an isolated system at constant volume”. An isolated system IS BY DEFINITION one of constant volume. This makes me suspect about the meaning of “isolated system”. Constant volume only insures no boundary work. It does not insure no heat transfer, which an isolated system (constant volume and adiabatic) does. So when you concluded with “What is a problem here”, the problem is the first statement. I will set up a Chat room and invite you, if you want.

Comment: @Bob D, well I thought that as well, but as I talked with others how we choose our reference state doesn't matter. If we take into account interatomic potential energy than internal energy U is U = KE + PE (microscopic kinetic energy + all potential energy of interaction). After exothermic reaction PE goes down and KE goes up while change in KE is the same change in PE due to energy conservation, so that U stays the same IF THE SYSTEM IS ISOLATED/ ADIABATIC.

Comment: If this is so why is it said that heat of reaction changes internal energy of the system if system is at constant volume? This can only be said for closed system at CONSTANT TEMPERATURE AND VOLUME which need to exchange heat with surroundings to keep the system at the same temperature, but for adibatic systems internal energy doesn't change because of arguments I have already given since system CAN'T EXCHANGE HEAT WITH SURROUNDINGS. Problem I had before is that energy balance for adiabatic reactors is written as heat of reaction being equal to change in internal energy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123625/discussion-between-dario-miric-and-bob-d).